# Center of finite dimensional division $\mathbb{R}$-algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $D$ be a finite dimensional division $\mathbb{R}$-algebra.

> Why is it that $Z(D)=\mathbb{R}$ or $Z(D)=\mathbb{C}$?

I have seen an explanation: It is because $\mathbb{C}$ is the only non trivial algebraic extension of $\mathbb{R}$.

But I don't get how does that explain it?

Thanks. I may be missing something trivial.

Comment: Center will be a field, finite over $\Bbb R$. There are only two such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $D$ is a division algebra, $Z(D)$ must be a field (it's easy to see that the inverse of a central element is also central).

Since $D$ is finite-dimensional over $\mathbb{R}$, $Z(D)$ is a finite field extension of $\mathbb{R}$ : it must be $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.